# I am unable to implement Connectivityresult in Liquidswipe

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I’m trying to use `OfflineBuilder` and `LiquidSwipe` but it’s not working and I’m not finding out why someone can help me? Thank you very much!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final pages = [
    //pagina1
    Container(
      color: connected ? Colors.purple[700] : color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.pink[700]
    ),
  ];

  return Scaffold(
    body: OfflineBuilder(
      connectivityBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        ConnectivityResult connectivity,
        Widget child,
      ) {
        final bool connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
        return LiquidSwipe(
          pages: pages,
          enableLoop: true,
          fullTransitionValue: 700,
          enableSlideIcon: false,
          waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
          positionSlideIcon: 0.7,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `connected` from the `OfflineBuilder`. Try this instead

```dart
final pages(bool connected) => [
      //pagina1
      Container(
        color: connected ? Colors.purple[700] : color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.pink[700]
      ),      
    ];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: OfflineBuilder(
          connectivityBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          ConnectivityResult connectivity,
          Widget child,
          ) {
            final bool connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
            return LiquidSwipe(
              pages: pages(connected),
              enableLoop: true,
              fullTransitionValue: 700,
              enableSlideIcon: false,
              waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
              positionSlideIcon: 0.7,
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello thank you so much for it’s already working but I had to make some changes to your code that were:
put the ending inside the widget and also had to take the end left only ```page (bool Connected)````